# django template dynamic table field row data

Tags: django, django-templates

I create django template dynamic table header,

I want to get the table header from another model, and get the data corresponding to the table header from the data model.

I want `{{ data.field_name }} <== {{data.{{ header.{{header.field_id}} }}`
but not working,

### My views.py

```py
from asset_manager.models import (
    AssetServiceCategory,
    AssetField,
)

from asset.models import (
    AssetList,
)


#---[ Start Views ]---#

#--[ Default Asset_manager View ]--#
class Asset_View(View):
    #-[ Resuest GET URL:asset ]-#
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/accounts/login/')
        else:
            template_name = [
                'asset/asset.html',
                'asset/asset/asset_service_category.html',
            ]
            service_category = AssetServiceCategory.objects.all()
            asset_list_header = AssetField.objects.filter(field_display="YES")
            asset_list_data = AssetList.objects.all()

            context = {
                'service_category': service_category,
                'asset_list_header' : asset_list_header,
                'asset_list_data' : asset_list_data,
            }
            return render(request, template_name, context)
```

### My asset_list.html

```html
<table class="table table_asset_list">
    <thead class="thead thead_asset_list">
        <tr>
            {% for header in asset_list_header %}
                <th>{{ header.field_name }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody tbody_asset_list">

        {% for header in asset_list_header %}
            {% for data in asset_list_data %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ data.{{header.field_id}} }}</td>   <== This is not working...
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```